# Why is this question downvoted so much?

Tags: support, down-votes

Why could be a likely reason that this question is being downvoted so much? I tried my best to improve the question (in the Update) but I am still not sure whether this helps.

[Is there a way to replace cmd window with the new windows terminal?](https://superuser.com/q/1469293/13079)

Comment: The update appears to have remedied the issues.

Comment: Maybe I'm just late, but I only see 1 upvote. That said, I've noticed that users on these Stack Exchange sites tend to be very anxious to hit that downvote button. It also probably doesn't help that there's actually a badge for downvoting a post.

Comment: I wonder if the downvotes are trying to say "the window isn't even coming from cmd.exe in the first place", i.e. "insufficient research"